# The value of scrollHeight is different from the actual height of the element. How to get the actual height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to build a masonry effect with CSS Grid, which requires getting the original height of the element and modifying the grid-row-end property accordingly. However, the scrollHeight attribute does not return the actual height of the element.

I use React together with Bootstrap, both the latest version.
I have tried other attributes like height, outerHeight, offsetHeight, clientHeight. No luck.

```
generateSpans() {
    const spans = [];
    Array.from(this.ref.current.children).forEach(child => {
        // This child has only one child element.
        const subChild = Array.from(child.children)[0];
        const childHeight = subChild.scrollHeight;
        const span = Math.ceil(childHeight / 10);
        spans.push(Math.ceil(span / 2) + 1);
    }); 
    this.setState({ spans });
}
```

For elements with a height of 216, 240, I get 166.
For elements with a height of 264, I get 190.
For elements with a height of 384, I get 214.
Any clue why this happens?

Thanks so much in advance.

EDIT 1:
I have tried to change scrollHeight to offsetHeight. The result is exactly the same as what is listed above.
[Here is the image of the elements that I inquire height of, the result, and the actual height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccQ0K.png)

EDIT 2:
Just tried window.getComputedStyle. The following is the modified code:

```
generateSpans() {
    const spans = [];
    Array.from(this.ref.current.children).forEach(child => {
        const subChild = Array.from(child.children)[0];
        const childHeight = window.getComputedStyle(subChild).getPropertyValue('height');
        console.log(subChild);
        console.log(childHeight);
        const span = Math.ceil(childHeight / 10);
        spans.push(Math.ceil(span / 2) + 1);
    }); 
    this.setState({ spans });
}
```

The result this time is a string. [Here is the image of the elements that I inquire height of, the result, and the actual height.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZzwz.png) But the value of it is no different.

Comment: I think you need to look here. This will solve your problem. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Comment: Sorry I should add: You need to call computed style in order to get the real value, this will give you attribute, code effects and css

Comment: You could try `offsetHeight` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight